Dynamically Generating Functions with Static Content
Right off the bat I want to say that I know and understand the potential security risks associated with executing dynamically generated content when it contains information provided by the user. This is, I think, a different scenario.
Imagine you're writing a CLI, and you have the following setup:
cmds=(
    "start"
    "stop"
    "reset"
)
declare -A errors

for cmd in "${cmds[@]}"; do
    errors[$cmd]=$((${#errors[@]} + 1))
done

function err() {
    echo "[error $1] $@" >&2
}

Now, when an error occurs -- parsing of a subcommand's arguments fails, for instance -- it can get a bit annoying to have to do the following everywhere:
if ! some_condition; then
    err "$subcmd" "$error_msg"
    exit ${errors[subcmd]}
fi

What I'd really like, is something like:
if ! some_condition; then
    ${subcmd}_error "$error_msg"
fi

because the error message format (as written in the err function) is generic, and the error code that will be used on exit is assigned per subcommand. The content of these subcommand error functions is going to be static as well: here's the error function for the stop subcommand, for example:
function stop_error() {
    err "stop" "$@"
    exit ${errors[stop]}
}

Every one of these subcommand error functions is going to look like this, but with "stop" substituted for a different subcommand. Now, because these subcommand error functions are small, and contain no user provided content (everything boils down to being placed in the string provided to echo anyway), I'd like to be able to dynamically generate them, so that I don't have 7 or 8 of the same functions sitting around.
But the following did not work for me, which is really the only way that I could think of how to achieve this:
for cmd in "${cmds[@]}"; do
    function ${cmd}_error() {
        err "$cmd" "$@"
        exit ${errors[$cmd]}
    }
done

Is there a way to dynamically generate functions in this way? Is evaling a string the only way to achieve this ?

Use eval to define the functions with dynamic names.

BTW, don't use the function statement. That is a ksh extension that was copied in bash, but it's not the standard way to define functions.

if the body of each function is (effectively) the same then you already have what you need ... a single function (err()) that takes subcmd as the 1st arg: : err "${subcmd}" "${error_msg}"; not sure I understand the need for an extra layer of obfuscation? though I'd probably add return "${errors[subcmd]}" to the current err() definition

Frame challenge: why is it important to be able to write ${subcmd}_error "$error_msg" instead of (say) error ${subcmd} "$error_msg"?

I would write it out. You have spent so much time writing a stackoveflow question - most probably it would be easier to write it Also Imagine you're writing a CLI, and you have the following setup: why would I want different cli subcommands exit with different values? That is confusing, just exit 1 from every cli command, I see no reason to implement different exit codes.


s there a way to dynamically generate functions in this way?

yes
for cmd in "${cmds[@]}"; do
    eval "function ${cmd}_error() {
        err \"\$cmd\" \"\$@\"
        exit \${errors[\$cmd]}
    }"
done


Is evaling a string the only way to achieve this ?

I would argue your approuch is just confusing. Just:
error() {
    err "$1" "${@:2}"
    exit ${errors[$1]}
}
if ! some_condition; then
    error "${subcmd}" "$error_msg"
fi

